# Arabic words handling with Regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex, arabic

I am trying to handle Arabic strings.

I want to handle multiple spaces between two strings (i.e. first name, last name).

But the RegEx that I am using is valid only for 1 spacing between the first name and last name.

RegEx used:

```
/^[\u0600-\u06FF]+([ ][\u0600-\u06FF]+)?$/
```

Please suggest.

Comment: are you talking about java or about javascript?

Comment: @stultuske : javascript

Comment: but regex would be same for both i think

Comment: Have you tried putting a `+` after `[ ]` ? You seem to know that  `+` means "one or more"

Comment: yes , worked fine !!! Thanks a ton buddy !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Simone Chelo, you need to add "+" to the regex. It means "one or more".
You also don't need to wrap the space with brackets.
This should work for you:

```
/^[\u0600-\u06FF]+( +[\u0600-\u06FF]+)?$/
```

If you want any kind of white space, you can use `\s` instead of `[ ]`

```
/^[\u0600-\u06FF]+(\s+[\u0600-\u06FF]+)?$/
```

[Here is a great resource for regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/).